# I have an ERROR with Three.js r69

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an error on line

```
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(vector));
```

In Three.js r36 it line is WORK.

```
var vector    = new THREE.Vector3(-300 + x/4, 240 - y, 0);
 geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(vector));
```

But in r69 it doesn't work. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The code should now look like this:

```
geometry.vertices.push(vector);
```